# Twitter card FetchError

Tags: twitter

I'm implementing Twitter cards on a website but am encountering an error.

This is the error I see when I check pages with [Twitter's card validator](https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator)

ERROR: FetchError:exceeded 4.seconds to Constructor while waiting for a response for the request, including retries (if applicable) (Card error)

It's possible that Twitter is saying I have a slow website, though it's much faster than 4 seconds. So I'm moving to a new host, but would be great if anyone's faced this problem before or can work out what the error message means.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this. The site was too slow. I moved to a new host and cards magically worked.